# Elasticsearch nest how to index polymorphically

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Ok,

Basically what I'd LIKE to do, is have a "Searchable" interface I implement on my entities, and have my repositories automatically call Index on save, and handle the update/delete accordingly. This all currently works. Ultimately I'd like to search against all these indicies and be able to give some sort of indicator of the type itself.

When I try to query them all back out... I use code that looks like this:

```
 eclient.Search<Searchable>(s => s.AllIndices().Query(q => q.QueryString(d => d.Query(query))))
```

I don't get anything back from this unless I explicitly specify the type I'd like to return.

Any pointers would be hugely appreciated. At this point my object model is changeable if interface/baseclass makes a difference etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to determine that my problem was actually more of a problem with what I was doing with the results. JavascriptSerializer didnt know how to properly serialize the objects, whereas json.net did a lot better job.